# Problem with international keyboard on 13.10

Tags: keyboard, 13.10, layout

I just upgraded my Ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10, but I got an issue. Usually the "' key" plus "c key" make the "ç", but since the update, it change this character to "altgr + <".

Anyone know why or how can I change it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that the problem was with system language. If you use English as the primary language, the '+c doesn't work as when the primary language is set to Portuguese-Brazil. Now, with pt-br as primary, it works as expected.